# How to avoid multiple repeat database queries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We are using asp.net mvc entity framework

We have a number of queries that represent large static data. Im wondering what is the best and simplest way to avoid querying the data each time.

We currently use a custom cache but it seems to have issues. Im wondering how others achieve this.

For example I have a locations data set that has over 10k records

Its used throughout the site and can be queried when the app starts doesn't need to get fetched again.

Comment: The solution is obviously caching. What issues does your custom cache have?

Comment: Yes but using what, how are you achieving this. a developer custom developed a caching module and its not performing well, thus Im looking for how others do it.

Comment: We store this kind of data as ```ConcurrentDictionary``` objects in the ```ObjectCache```. We use a separate dictionary for each index/attribute you search by. The dictionaries are lazy loaded.

Comment: we need to know what issue that you are facing, tell us the behavior and what your custom cache is built on.

Comment: the best way is caching but if you want don't use from cache you can set a flag when in your locations loded set it true and when you want load it check  this flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache

Maybe this helps:

```
void SomeAction()
{
    var test1 = LoadIds();
    var test2 = LoadIds();
    // test1 & test2 should be the same
}

int[] LoadIds() {
    var random = new Random();
    return MemoryCache.Default.GetCached("LoadIds", 60, () => new int[10].Select(x => random.Next()).ToArray() );
}

public static class CacheExtensions {
    public static T GetCached<T>(this ObjectCache cache, string key, int cacheTime, Func<T> acquire) 
    {
        if (cache.Contains(key))
            return (T) cache[key];

        var result = acquire();
        if (cacheTime > 0)
            cache.Add(new CacheItem(key, result), new CacheItemPolicy {AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheTime)});
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now instead of using this random initialization...

```
MemoryCache.Default.GetCached("LoadIds", 60, () => new int[10].Select(x => random.Next()).ToArray());
```

... you can use your query. Just make sure to add a .ToList() or .ToArray() at the end, since you want to cache the data and not the just the query. e.g.

```
MemoryCache.Default.GetCached("LoadIds", 60, () => dbContext.Persons.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray());
```

Or in your case maybe

```
MemoryCache.Default.GetCached("LoadLocations", 60, () => dbContext.Locations.ToArray());
```

This extension method above is not perfect though. In case that two requests access the same content at the same time it might double load that data...

I'm using this method in large scale web apps, while abstracting out the MemoryCache in order to replace it with other types of caches like Redis, azure storage or even the HttpContext.Current.Items for caches per request.